# Query Asking for Parameters for tables in WHERE clause when executed

Tags: sql, parameters, where-clause

I'm trying to filter my data. Some fool decided to be doc1,2,3,4 etc instead of just a document field. I'm trying to figure out how to filter any of them that contain the number 11.

Here's what I've got:

```
WHERE Em.CorpID = '380' 
AND (Ew.DocRcvd1 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd2 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd3 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd4 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd5 <> 11) 
AND (Ew.SSI = 1 OR Ew.VocRehab = 1 OR XFelon = 1)
```

When executed, the

```
 AND (Ew.DocRcvd1 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd2 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd3 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd4 <> 11 AND Ew.DocRcvd5 <> 11)
```

Asks for parameters for each of the tables listed, I've tried entering 11 or canceling, but no cigar.

Any idea's why this is happening and how I can get this puppy going?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, please take some time to rewrite it. Btw I can se only teo aliases (Ew and Em) and not the actual tables in your snipts. you dont used a alias before xfelon thus if that field ocurs in more than a table your query ill fail to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The Parameter was being asked for the column DocRdvd because the column that I wanted to reference was in actuality called DocRecvd.
I feel stupid. Hopefully someone else will find this helpful in the future, though.